# Как распознать редирект с помощью java в http запросе?

Tags: java, javafx, http-status-code-404, jsonp

Собственно проблема заключается в следующем, делаю http запрос на сайт по определенной ссылке, мне нужно проверить существует данный url или нет. Вот кусок кода:

```html
 for (int i = 0; i < Str.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                         url= hostValue.getText();
                        url= url+Str.get(i);
                        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
                                .timeout(10000).ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                                .execute();

                        int statusCode = response.statusCode();
                        System.out.println("io - " + response.statusCode()+response.url());

                        if (statusCode == 200) {
                            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                            Elements element = doc.select("html");
                            if (element != null){
                                //ResultsValues.appendText(url + "200" + "true"+"\n");
                                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        ResultsGoods.appendText(url+"  "+statusCode+"  "+"TRUE" +"\n");
                                    }
                                });}

                            else {
                                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    ResultsGoods.appendText(url+"  "+statusCode+"  "+"FALSE" +"\n");
                                }
                            });}
```

Далее я проверяю теги html на данной странице, есть или нет.Весь код работает, проблем с этим нет. Сама проблема заключается в том, что сайт отдает мне код 200 OK, и редиректит меня на страницу 404 (данная страница не существует, например 404.html). Как мне обойти данный момент, т.е. определить что сервер перебрасывает меня на другую страницу, без кода 301 или 302.

Comment: Ради теста попробуйте запросить подобную страницу через обычный HttpClient. Он уж точно работает в чистом http протоколе и отредиректится может только по http коду и то если вы его попросите. Если вам от jsonp больше ничего и не надо может и использовать более низкоуровневый объект?

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, на выходе тоже самое Sending 'GET' request to URL : https://www.*********/index.php
Response Code : 200   и подсовывает  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.*****/error404.php"/>

Comment: Ну так если этой страницы не существует, то оно так и будет, вы просто теперь сможете искать данный текст для определения что это по факту 404 а не 200

Comment: Ну да мне в принципе и интересен данный вопрос, как определить что он редиректит на 404 хотя отдает 200 OK, если бы он отдавал 301 или 302 проблем бы не было, собственно мне нужно фильтровать такие ссылки которые действительно существуют, а которые нет.

Comment: Ну в итоге концептуально ваш вопрос решен или надо дать полный ответ уже с деталями реализации как отличить 200 от 404?

Comment: Мне нужен совет как отличать 404 страницу, при ответе 200 OK(без редиректа), парсить содержимое в странице404 и искать на странице число '404' или есть более не костыльные методы?

Comment: Если статус ответа 200 перепроверять и искать в содержимом вхождение ink rel="canonical" href="www.*****/error404.php. Другого варианта вам серверная часть, которая отвечает вам на запрос попросту не дает.

Comment: Это я согласен как вариант решения, но сайтов может быть много и не везде перенаправление идет именно на эту ссылку error404.php, как быть?Нужно какое то более универсальное решение,например искать '404' в ответе.

Comment: В задаче не было информации что это один из сайтов. Ну в любом случае вы вынуждены подстраиваться под реалии запрашиваемого ресурса. Чтобы инкапсулировать спец логику для спец сайта советую использовать паттерн стратегия. Позднее смогу дать более полный ответ с примером

Comment: буду благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Собственно добавил условие проверки вхождения '404' в ответ, вроде работает. Но если будет более красивое решение, просьба написать в комментрии.
Код к примеру выше:

```html
if (statusCode == 200) {
                            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                            Elements element = doc.select("html");
                            if (element != null && !element.text().contains("404")){
                                //ResultsValues.appendText(url + "200" + "true"+"\n");
                                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        scanResultsGoods.appendText(url+"  "+statusCode+"  "+"TRUE" +"\n");
                                    }
                                });}
```

Comment: Не надёжное решение - в коде любой страницы может быть число `404`, не имеющее никакого отношения к этой ошибке. Нужно посмотреть коды нескольких вариантов и найти у них общее, выделяющее среди других. Условный пример: это обязан быть адрес ссылки и сама ссылка единственной в коде страницы.

Comment: C вами полностью согласен дикий костыль, но у разных сайтов будет разное содержимое в странице 404, как же найти что то общее?